# SQL Server sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a sequence group by a particular column.

I have a table `LoanMaster` and there is a column called `BranchCode`. It has branches 1 - 48. I want to generate a sequence number per branch. Like for branch code 1, if it has 10 records then generate a sequence number from 1 - 10, then for branch code 2 if it has 15 records generate number from 1 - 15 and so on.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT 
   BranchCode,
   [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BranchCode ORDER BY BranchCode)
FROM LoanMaster
ORDER BY BranchCode, rn
```

#EDIT:#

To start from arbitrary value just add it:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f402/2/0)**

```
SELECT 
   BranchCode,
   [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BranchCode ORDER BY BranchCode) + 100
FROM LoanMaster
ORDER BY BranchCode, rn
```

#EDIT 2:#

**[Demo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/368249)**

```
CREATE TABLE #LoanMaster(Id INT, LeadsID1 INT, LBrCode INT);

INSERT INTO #LoanMaster(Id, LBrCode)
VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,2), (6,2), (7,2);

;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT
     Id,
     LBrCode,
     [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LBrCode ORDER BY LBrCode) + 2405 
   FROM #LoanMaster
)
UPDATE T1
SET LeadsID1=c.RowNumber
FROM #LoanMaster AS T1 
JOIN cte c 
  ON c.LBrCode=T1.LBrCode 
 AND c.Id = T1.Id
WHERE c.LBrCode=1;

SELECT *
FROM #LoanMaster;
```

This is my last update (accept answer or not) because initial question was answered long ago, for future:

- you should ask specific question
- provide actual table structures + [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)
- provide desired output
- specify what you want to achieve query/update
- specify edge cases

Writing in comments more and more demands is not how SO works.

Comment: If I want to generate from 100 on wards how is it possible to use ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: @DeEDEe `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BranchCode ORDER BY BranchCode) + 100`

Comment: Mines generating the same number:UPDATE LoanMaster SET LeadsID1=T1.RowNumber
FROM (SELECT 
   LBrCode,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LBrCode ORDER BY LBrCode) + 2405 AS 'RowNumber' FROM LoanMaster
    ) AS T1 JOIN
   LoanMaster S ON S.LBrCode=T1.LBrCode
WHERE S.LBrCode=1